# Editable list using php mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, list, phpmyadmin

I'm a beginner to this whole mySQL thing and I am working on my first website. I understand how to setup the database I would need for this, but am unsure how I would implement it. I want to allow logged-in members to add input into a list such as the following:

First Name | Last Name | Timestamp | Poster

I want this to be saved to the database. Ideally the member will be able to input into the first two columns and the "timestamp" and "poster" will be automatically filled out. I'm not necessarily looking for a full explanation but maybe someone to point me in the right direction.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: presumably you've got a login system, so your code would already know WHO is submitting the data. after that it's just a simple `insert` query...

Comment: there is plenty of examples of this in here:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: would this also allow me to display the information inserted into the database on the page?

Comment: Too broad. Just find a PHP database tutorial.  Make sure to use one that is not using the old deprecated `mysql_` functions. Use `mysqli_` or PDO.

Comment: `would this also allow me to display...` There's also a "select data" tutorial at the link RicardoE provided. Look at the side panel under "MySQL Database."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the timestamp field, you can use a default value, although it is usually best to have your application handling such things (say using an ORM).

To default to the current time, in the mysql console, type:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable CHANGE COLUMN myColumn DEFAULT TIMESTAMP;
```

For the user, this will need to be inserted by your application unless you only have 1 user. You should really look at using some sort of Framework to handle these tasks.